# ASP.NET(VB) Listboxes are not moving all the selected items to other Listboxes

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox

The DivisionListBox is used to select values in the SitesListbox as follows: When you select an item in the DivisionListBox it will select all the items on SitesListbox that match the same value.

Once the SiteListbox values are selected I use the SiteButton to move all selected values to the empty StoreslistBox successfully.

My problem happens when I manually select multiple items on either SiteListbox or StoreslistBox and press SiteButton or StoreButton to move items between Listboxes. It either moves one item at a time or some of the selected items but it never moves all of the selected items (which can be track by the labels).

What is causing this problem and what could be a possible solution for this?

**My code**

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    DivisionSelection()

End Sub

Private Sub DivisionSelection()

    If DivisionListBox.SelectedValue IsNot Nothing Then
        SitesListBox.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple
        For Each item As ListItem In SitesListBox.Items
            If item.Value = DivisionListBox.SelectedValue Then
                item.Selected = True
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim Siteitem As ListItem
    For Each Siteitem In SitesListBox.Items
        If Siteitem.Selected Then
            x += 1
            Label1.Text = x
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Protected Sub SiteButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles SiteButton.Click

    StoresListBox.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple
    While SitesListBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing
        StoresListBox.Items.Add(SitesListBox.SelectedItem)
        SitesListBox.Items.Remove(SitesListBox.SelectedItem)
    End While

    'counts the selected items
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim Siteitem As ListItem
    For Each Siteitem In SitesListBox.Items
        If Siteitem.Selected Then
            x += 1
            Label1.Text = x
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Protected Sub StoreButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles StoreButton.Click

    StoresListBox.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple
    While StoresListBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing
        SitesListBox.Items.Add(StoresListBox.SelectedItem)
        StoresListBox.Items.Remove(StoresListBox.SelectedItem)
    End While

    'counts the selected items
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Dim Storeitem As ListItem
    For Each Storeitem In SitesListBox.Items
        If Storeitem.Selected Then
            x += 1
            Label2.Text = x
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: @LarsTech when i use SelectedItem i get the following error:
'SelectedItems' is not a member of ListBox'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added the selected items to a list; then looped through the list to do the adding and removing. When a collection or indexes are messed with inside a loop it can have unexpected results.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim lstItems As New List(Of ListItem)
    For Each item As ListItem In ListBox1.Items
        If item.Selected Then
            lstItems.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
    'It wasn't clear if you wanted the items to remain selected after moving.
    ListBox1.ClearSelection()
    Debug.Print(lstItems.Count.ToString)
    For Each item As ListItem In lstItems
        ListBox2.Items.Add(item)
        ListBox1.Items.Remove(item)
    Next
End Sub
```