# asp.net vb listbox item selection is not working correctly

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, listbox

What I've been trying to do is to move items from SitesListbox to StoresListbox which is an empty listbox. The SitesListbox is connected to a DB via an SqlDataSource which generates the items. On the SitesListbox when one or multiple items are selected and the move button is clicked it moves the incorrect items.

Ex. I select the 101 Store and press and it moves the 100 store.

1. 100 store
2. 101 store
3. 102 store

What could be causing this error and how can i fix it?

so far i tried the following methods in the button function with the same results so i suspect it could be something else im not seeing.

**Method 1**

```
While SitesListBox.SelectedItem IsNot Nothing
        StoresListBox.Items.Add(SitesListBox.SelectedItem)
        SitesListBox.Items.Remove(SitesListBox.SelectedItem)
    End While
```

**Method 2**

```
Dim lstItems As New List(Of ListItem)
    For Each item As ListItem In SitesListBox.Items
        If item.Selected Then
            lstItems.Add(item)
        End If
    Next
    SitesListBox.ClearSelection()
    For Each item As ListItem In lstItems
        StoresListBox.Items.Add(item)
        SitesListBox.Items.Remove(item)
    Next
```

**Method 3**

```
Dim itemsToRemove As New List(Of ListItem)
    For Each item As ListItem In SitesListBox.Items
        If item.Selected And Not StoresListBox.Items.Contains(item) Then
            Dim newItem As New ListItem(item.Text, item.Value)
            StoresListBox.Items.Add(newItem)
            itemsToRemove.Add(item)
        End If
    Next

    For Each item As ListItem In itemsToRemove
        SitesListBox.Items.Remove(item)
    Next
```

**Update**

After some experimenting i discovered that all three methods work fine after i removed the SqlDataSource and added a few items manually to test each method. The incorrect item selection happens the SitesListbox items are generated with the SqlDataSource.

Why does this happened?

Comment: I recognize my method (Method 2) from your previous question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64395042/asp-netvb-listboxes-are-not-moving-all-the-selected-items-to-other-listboxes  I tried testing again with a databound list box and it is still working for me.

Comment: @Mary I removed the SqlDataSource from the listbox and added the values manually and all three methods started to work correctly. The problem happens when the listbox items are generated from an SqlDataSource that the item selection doesn't work correctly. ej. I select store 500 and move it and the value that moves is store 101